# If a sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers has a convergent subsequence, then it must be bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the following claim correct?

$Claim:$ If a sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers has a convergent subsequence, then it must be bounded.

I intuitively feel that the answer is no since one could (possibly) construct some oscillating sequence/function that, say, on odd values of $n$ would dance in a bounded section of $\mathbb{R}$ and, say, on even values would diverge to $+\infty$. (Additionally, the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem statement would have been stronger if the claim was true.)

Can someone possibly provide a counter-example?

Comment: Your idea is good.  Take $a_n=( (-1)^n+1)n$, say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is false. Consider the sequence $(0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,\ldots)$.
It has a sequence that converges to $0$ but the sequence itself is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example might be something like $$a_n = \left( (-1)^n+1\right)n$$

We see that for even $n$ the term $a_n=2n$, while for odd $n$, $a_n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. In fact, take any unbounded sequence $a_n$ and any convergent sequence $b_n$ and let

$$ c_n = \begin{cases} a_{1/2(i+1)} & i=1,3,5... \\ b_{i/2} & i=2,4,6...  \end{cases} $$

Then $c_n$ will have a convergent subsequence $c_{2n}$ but will still be unbounded.